What happens to the second oxygen in the imbalanced product of magnesium oxide?
I was told that to determine the product of $\ce{Mg + O2}$, you find the most simplified and neutral molecule the given reactants could form, being $\ce{MgO}$. While I know there is a balanced version of $\ce{Mg + O2 -> MgO}$ and that it's a synthesis reaction, is there any compensation for the extra $\ce{O}$ lost in $\ce{MgO}$ other than balancing? If you had only one $\ce{Mg}$ and one $\ce{O2}$ and react them, is the extra oxygen the heat the two give off?

Chemical reaction equations are nothing else but a special syntax for a set of mathematical equations. This set tells you that for each element, the number of its atoms must be equal on both reaction sides. No atom is created nor destroyed.
If you really have just $\ce{1 Mg}$ atom and $\ce{1 O2}$ molecule, there are two reaction options,
$$\ce{Mg + O2 -> MgO + O}$$
$$\ce{Mg + O2 -> MgO2}$$
forming magnesium oxide or peroxide. But these reactions would not happen in bulk but in traces. There would be created $\ce{MgO}$ and remained the excess of either of reactants.
$$\ce{2 Mg + O2 -> 2 MgO}$$

Well, it is the case of stoichiometry and limiting reagent. You have to understand that this reaction takes place in the presence of excess $\ce{O2}$. That means, there will be enough oxygen for $\ce{Mg}$ to react with. But when we restrict the reaction to take place with one mole of oxygen and one mole of $\ce{Mg}$, half mole of oxygen remains. This amount of oxygen stays as it is. If we restrict the amount of oxygen and give magnesium in excess, then the required amount of magnesium with react with the oxygen, the oxygen will completely be used up. Remaining $\ce{Mg}$ will remain as it is.
Now if you somehow hypothetically separate one molecule of $\ce{Mg}$ (well, $\ce{Mg}$ exists as atom so one atom will be more appropriate) and one molecule of oxygen, then the reaction will proceed by breaking the oxygen oxygen double bond and forming $\ce{Mg-O}$ bond (mostly ionic) and nascent oxygen $\ce{[O]}$ will be released. This nascent atomic oxygen will react with some other material if present in the reaction mixture as nascent Oxygen is a good oxidising agent. Peroxides may also form like $\ce{MgO2}$. What happens in a reaction mixture is that when oxygen is in excess, the nascent Oxygen atoms that are formed quickly react with each other. In the reaction mixture many products may form but one dominates others. Here, $\ce{MgO}$ dominates traces of $\ce{MgO2}$. This thing is more evident in organic reactions where significant amounts of other products are obtained.
Oxygen is not the heat. Oxygen remains as it is. The energy is released as heat when Magnesium and oxygen reacts to form $\ce{MgO}$. This is highly exothermic as the new bond formation reduces the energy level of both the reactants. This energy that is lowered is released as heat. You may ask if the reaction is exothermic then why we initially burn the reactants. This is called activation energy. This is like an initial push to a rolling object from a hill top to the valley. The activation energy initially breaks the $\ce{O-O}$ double bonds and then when the reaction starts the energy released due to new bond formation is sufficient to break the $\ce{O-O}$ double bonds further.
So, a chemical reaction has only one form, that is the stoichiometric balanced form. This is not a version but it is the reality. The reaction proceeds in the stoichiometric ratio. If one is excess in practice, then the limiting reagent will use only the required amount and the remaining amount will just hang around. Chemical reaction is about the probability of collision of the reactants in the right orientation. Alternative orientation might just revert the reaction or make alternate products.
\begin{gather}
\ce{Mg + O_2 -> MgO + [O]}\\
\text{or}\\
\ce{Mg + O_2 -> MgO_2}
\end{gather}

You don't actually need to use <br> or <p>…</p> statements for breaking up paragraphs. What you enter here is Markdown, you indicate the end of a paragraph by a blank line. The rest is done automatically. Makes formatting a lot easier…
